Do Firefox addons/browser extensions have the ability to trigger keyboard shortcuts?
On Firefox, there used to be a button that enabled Picture in Picture video. But I used some Firefox CSS theme and now it isn't there anymore. Now, i could try making an extension that does picture in picture for me but that's hard, instead I could try making an extension the presses the keybind "Ctrl + Shift + ]" for me so picture in picture triggers, can an extension do that or does it violate some security feature? See my overflow post for more info.
For clarity, since some users didn't understand,
The extension's icon (which typically appears at the top of the browser), when pressed, should trigger a keyboard shortcut.
For example: Let's say I wanted to make a copy extension, I select some text, drag my cursor to the top of my browser, click the extension's icon, and the extension should copy the text

I don't think I was clear enough, i want an extension, that when pressed, triggers a shortcut.
For example: IF i clicked the icon of an extension in top toolbar, it should be the equivalent of pressing Ctrl + V

At one time, Firefox allowed applications to be launched from a Bookmark, which would have been an answer: create a .bat file with the keystrokes and pin it to the Bookmarks bar. However, I do not believe that is available, now, for obvious security reasons.
